# rails 3.1 - jquery plugin for ajax upload

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, ajax-upload

I want to install plugin for ajax upload in Rails 3.1.

How to do that? Just execute `git clone` in `vendor/`?

What about asset pipeline? I must specify some code like that in `application.js`?

`//= require vendor/file-upload`

Do you know better plugin for ajax file upload, than this one?

https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

**UPDATE**

I want to upload file without clicking submit, so **remotipart** doesnt apply to that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of installing plugins under ./vendor (that's the old Rails way), 
you should look for a GEM which does the functionality, and **add the Gem to the Gemfile, 
then run `bundle install`.**

e.g. add this to your ./Gemfile :

```
gem 'name_of_the_gem' , "version_number"  # the version_number is optional
```

then run `bundle install`

There are a couple of gems available for file-uploading, some of them support AJAX.
e.g.:

- Remotipart http://www.alfajango.com/blog/remotipart-rails-gem/
  and  http://thechangelog.com/post/7576700785/remotipart-rails-3-ajax-file-uploads-made-easy

---

**Plugin Installation on Rails 3:**

```
$ rails plugin install http://wherever.com/somewhere/plugin_name.git
```

or

```
cd vendor/plugins

git clone -q http://wherever.com/somewhere/plugin_name.git
```

or

```
git submodule add http://wherever.com/somewhere/plugin_name.git vendor/plugins/plugin_name
```

Comment: Ok. This will probably work fine. But what about if I want to install  the jquery plugin directly without adding a gem? Can you provide a solution to that problem? You could leave it for others..

Comment: I want to upload file without clicking submit button, so remotipart tutorials dont apply to that.